# CakePHP: Encrypt password in config file

Tags: cakephp, configuration, password-encryption

I don't want to store my password for my database configuration in plain text in the database.php for revision control reasons.

I want something like this:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => simpleEncryptFunction('v3RyH4rD3NcRyPtEdPaS$wOrD'),
    'database' => 'sample',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

private function simpleEncryptFunction($hardPassword == null) {
   // Some pretty easy decrypt code. Not safe at all but I don't care.
   // It just shouldn't be that easy for people who don't understand code. 
}
```

Comment: And now you expect someone two write it for you? Sorry, but that's not how SO works, not to mention that there are already many questions regarding **passwords in version control**, just do a google search, read them, and understand why your approach is flawed from the very beginning.

Comment: I just wanted to ask if there's an easy approach.. Sorry dude. It's not only about version control, it's also about some people have access to a server where our application is deployed.

Comment: I dont think that you get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ndm's comment is right, your approach **is** flawed. Instead do this:

- Create a `database.default.php` and put the default values in it **without** passwords and commit it.
- Put `database.php` in your `.gitignore`, this file should **never** going to be committed.
- Change your deploy script to automatically copy `database.default.php` to `default.php` and replace the password value with whatever is needed
- For development your developers will have to do it manually (or by a script)

The same concept can be applied to `bootstrap.php` as well. And [check this plugin out](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-environments), we're using it for a project to have multiple environments configured and loaded conditionally.